# Apple's magnetic charging port has been patented, but why wasn't a search engine?

Tags: patents

Apple's [magnetic port has been patented](https://www.google.com/patents/US7311526), and now no other company can use the same idea to build its charging ports. If this can be achieved for a charging port, I was wondering why a search engine or an e-commerce platform per se can't be patented so that no other competitor would start working on it.

Answer (score 2):

Explanations of Apple's MagSafe patent are [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/8382/10).

[The USPTO explains what can be patented under U.S. statute](https://www.uspto.gov/patents-getting-started/general-information-concerning-patents#heading-4) (which is generally informative for all member countries of the [Patent Cooperation Treaty](http://www.wipo.int/pct/en/)):

> [A]ny person who “invents or discovers any new and useful process,
> machine, manufacture, or composition of matter, or any new and useful
> improvement thereof, may obtain a patent,” subject to the conditions
> and requirements of the law. The word “process” is defined by law as a
> process, act, or method, and primarily includes industrial or
> technical processes. The term “machine” used in the statute needs no
> explanation. The term “manufacture” refers to articles that are made,
> and includes all manufactured articles. The term “composition of
> matter” relates to chemical compositions and may include mixtures of
> ingredients as well as new chemical compounds. These classes of
> subject matter taken together include practically everything that is
> made by man and the processes for making the products.
>
> Interpretations of the statute by the courts have defined the limits
> of the field of subject matter that can be patented, thus it has been
> held that the laws of nature, physical phenomena, and abstract ideas
> are not patentable subject matter.
>
> A patent cannot be obtained upon a
> mere idea or suggestion. The patent is granted upon the new machine,
> manufacture, etc., as has been said, and not upon the idea or
> suggestion of the new machine. A complete description of the actual
> machine or other subject matter for which a patent is sought is
> required.

As noted [here](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/18182/10):

> Despite the best efforts of patent offices many patents are granted
> that may not meet these criteria: that's why a patent can be
> challenged in court. An invalid patent may stand for many years (or
> even expire) without ever being reviewed by a court.

It is possible to win and enforce a patent that might not withstand a vigorous administrative or legal challenge.

In fact, [there is a great deal of ongoing rule- and law-making regarding what can be patented](http://www.intellectualpropertylawblog.com/archives/software-and-business-method-inventions-after-alice).  It *is* possible to patent things that you might consider to cover a "search engine" or "e-commerce platform.  For example, [Amazon.com famously patented "one-click" ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-Click#Patent) in the U.S., but its application with the European Patent Office was refused.